# AD844 TZ and offset null pin connection

Tags: operational-amplifier, connect

I want to use AD844 op amp to amplify signals at about 11 MHz.

I just want to build the following circuit configurations: inverting gain of 1, 10 and non-inverting gain of 1, 10 and 100.

These configurations have also be illustrated in the datasheet. But I could not see any clear hint about what to do with the TZ pin and the null pins if I do not want to use them.

Now my question is, what should I do with the TZ pin and the null pins, in light of what I want to do with the op amp, as I have mentioned. Should I keep them disconnected, or connect to ground, or what?

Here is a link to the datasheet:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD844.pdf

Comment: You won't get a gain of 100 at 11 MHz.

Comment: It's a high speed op amp and it’s meant to do that.

Comment: Non-inverting (gain of 100) 3 dB point is typically 9 MHz on +/-15 volt rails and typically 5 MHz on +/- 5 volt rails but, if you say you can achieve 11 MHz bandwidth with gain at +100 then good luck.

Comment: Ok. You are right, the gain at 11 MHz would not be 100 (or 70). Hope gain of 50 (or 40) would work. This was not my actual question though.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the NULL and TZ pins disconnected, if you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks bro. You sure about that?

Comment: Yes, because it reads in the datasheet you linked that the use of those pins is optional, and the examples that do not use those pins don't even mention those pins.

Comment: Ok. Hope you are correct. (I think you are.)